# Can I add a checkbox option through script from a form made without any script to it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I created a form without using google script and then made a script that opens the form by Id. I want to know if I can add a checkbox choice to the second checkbox question on the form.
So what I came up with is in another function I create what the option will be and pass it to addOption. The way I did it works but it replaces whatever I previously added to the item. I guess now the question is how do I add more options without it replacing the previous one.

```
function addOption(option) {
  var a = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX)[1].asCheckboxItem();
  a.setChoiceValues(option);
}
```

Comment: Add your script to your question so that we can see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Yes```````.```````

Comment: I added some code

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Assuming you just want to add one option to your already existing options.

The problem in your code is that you use the function setChoicesValues() [1] to override all the previous choices with the new choice. You first need to obtain the choices array, add the new choice to the array and then set the new choices array to the CheckboxItem.

Another thing is that in this case, it’s better to use setChoices [1] instead of setChoicesValues [1] because setChoicesValues works with a String array, and what you obtain from getChoices [1] is a Choice array. So basically, it’s easier to just create the new Choice object and add it to the Choice array than loop through the Choices array, get the string of each Choice and create a string Array with this (and adding the new string choice).

I tweaked a bit your code, tested and worked successfully:

```
function addOption() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('XXXXX');
  var option = "IT WORKS";

  var a = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX)[1].asCheckboxItem();

 //Create the choice object 
  var option = a.createChoice(option);

//Get all the choices and add the new one to the array
  var options = a.getChoices();
  options.push(option);

//Set the new choices using the Choice array
  a.setChoices(options);
}
```

I used the option variable as a string and then created the Choice object, if you’re already passing the option parameter as a Choice object you should delete that line.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-item